# When using the WorkBook.SaveAs method is there a way to get the full file path with extension after creating the file? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am using the following code to write an array to a new workbook and save it.

```
'@Ignore ImplicitPublicMember
Sub ArrayToCsvWorkborkMethod(ByVal MyArray As Variant, ByVal FileName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Add
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = WB.Sheets.[_Default](1)
    
    'Print array to sheet in new workbook
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), UBound(MyArray, 2))
    Target.Value = MyArray
    
    WB.SaveAs FileName, 62                       'Maybe this should be 23 idk lol
    
    WB.Close
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
```

I than pass the file name to a function which shows a custom confirmation box for the user.

```
    'Below code runs on success
    FileWrittenMsgBox FileName & ".csv"
ErrHandler:
End Sub
```

[image]

Right now i am currently just adding the CSV extension manually however this is unsatisfying and not dynamic. When using WorkBook.SaveAs method is there a way to get the full path after saving? I want to make this code more general purpose

Also as a sidebar is there a functional difference between 62 and 23 if i am not using special characters?

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Right before WB.Close use `Debug.Print WB.FullName` or use the variable: `Filename = WB.FullName`.

Comment: @Toddleson WB.Name does not appear to give me the extension. However i reworked things a bit. Now when i call ArrayToCsvWorkborkMethod Filename already has extension CSV. This means i can rename it to ArrayToWorkborkMethod and feed it any workbook extension.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thats exactly what i was looking for thank you!